# Display picture gallery in portal

Tags: javascript, html, liferay

I am using Liferay portal and want to display pictures on it, the portal has Image Gallery, but it's too confusing, I just want simple coverflow-like display - big image on top plus thumbnails or next/previous button.

Is there a way to implement it in javascript only assuming I have a list of images?

Answer (score 0):

There are many javascript libraries available to achieve this, one which comes to mind is [Colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox).

**Some considerations:**

If you want to display the images in Image Gallery built-in portlet then you would need a hook to modify liferay's code (for Image Gallery display portlet) and include your own javascript to do it.

Or else

You can also make a plugin portlet yourself and make use of Liferay's Image Gallery API to fetch images and show them using custom javascript library. The advantage of this approach would be that you would have more freedom in how you want to show and what you want to show and also you don't have to deal with a whole of liferay jsp code in the built-in portlet.

**Note:** Starting from **Liferay 6.1** there is no separate Image Gallery portlet, instead it is combined in one `Documents & Media portlet` and it has two distinct display portlets: `Document Library Display portlet` and `Media display portlet`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a [default web content hook](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lportal/files/Liferay%20Plugins/6.1.0%20GA1/default-web-content-hook-6.1.0.1-ce-ga1-20120106155615760.war/download) that will provide a structure and template (elements of web content management) in the global scope (Carousel). With these you can create an article referencing the images and the proposed size. The template will take care of the rest of the rendering.

If it doesn't meet your needs, you might take it as a starting point. At least it's a nice way to separate the choice of images from the presentation.

Comment: I mainly need to have a list of image URLs in a "folder" with pictures, so I can pass it to some javascript libraries. The way the image gallery looks right now is not really appealing and intuitive, I just want something like providing starting folder as a parameter and it would display the thumbnails and a picture with forward/back buttons and possibly a slideshow.